# Manually Reading a Minibacth contents in CNTK

Tags: python, machine-learning, cntk

I am modifying the [CNTK 103B MNIST Tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_103B_MNIST_FeedForwardNetwork.ipynb) to read PNG files directly instead of the original text file. I am having problems in having the model converge when I make the change, and would like to inspect the contents of the minibatches that are being read from PNG files to make sure this is not the reason the model stops working after changing the source of training data.

After this code:

```
mb = reader_test.next_minibatch(test_minibatch_size, input_map=input_map)
```

Is there a way to inspect the contents of the minibatch in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mb is just a dictionary from variables to minibatch_data. Minibatch data has a .value attribute you can use to see the minibatch as a numpy array. So something like

`for var in mb:
    print('minibatch data for variable "%s" with shape %s'%(var.name, var.shape))
    print(mb[var].value)`

will work. However, printing a 784 dense vector will likely not be very helpful. Fortunately, it is easy to reshape each element of the minibatch to a 28 x 28 square and display it as an image inside the notebook.

Comment: This worked. I was able to plot the images red by the minibatch. I found that the image deserializer is not reading the 1 channel PNG images correctly. The image that is loaded is not the original PNG, but some white horizontal bands, mostly at the bottom half of the image.  This is the code that creates the MinibatchSource:  `return MinibatchSource(ImageDeserializer(map_file, StreamDefs(   features = StreamDef(field='image', transforms=transforms), labels   = StreamDef(field='label', shape=10)))`  transforms: `ImageDeserializer.scale(width=28, height=28, channels=1, interpolations='linear')`

Comment: This is the reason why the model doesn't work. Is there any specific way to load PNG 1-channel files? Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: We rely on opencv for loading images. If opencv cannot handle the image format correctly you have two options: 
a) convert the image to a different format (We have had  reports that opencv doesn't handle 16bit channels correctly, maybe you can convert your image to 8bit if it is 16bit) 
b) load the image in a different way e.g. with PIL and feed it manually (i.e. without a reader). If you are using a pretrained network, see this wiki page for details: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Evaluate-a-saved-convolutional-network

Comment: Ok, I will see if this has something to do with 16 bit channels. I just created a github repository with: examples of 2 plots of how the images are read, the code used to convert MNIST to PNG files, and some example MNIST digits in PNG format: [https://github.com/davidarh/cntk_images_png](Link)

Comment: Thanks David, the files are actually 32 bits, can you try the following:

"w = png.Writer(cols, rows, greyscale=True, bitdepth=8)"